# Difference in Control Flow Graph (CFG) of bytecode having vulnerability and after fixing the vulnerability in Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, bytecode, opcode, vulnerability

I was analyzing the Control Flow Graph (CFG) extraction from ByteCode by EtherSolve and then thought about an interesting question, how CFG of vulnerable smart contract gets changed after fixing this vulnerability.

Comment: What does it mean "CFG"?

Comment: Control Flow Graph

Comment: I am working on smth similar let's chat if you are interested